# Translated versions of my website are not indexed by Google - what should I do?

Tags: google

I have developed a web application - at the bottom of the homepage there are links to translated versions of it.

You can visit http://www.plancake.com to have an idea of what I am talking about.

The links are like this one:

<a href="http://www.plancake.com/it/"> <img src="/images/flags/small/it.png">   Italiano </a>

They are there for more than 1 month and I have submitted them to Google using the WebMaster tools more than two weeks ago.

Thing is that when I search a text from the homepage (from the translated version) in Google my website doesn't come up.

What should I do? Building a sitemap.xml is the way to go or that is now outdated and I should do something different?

Thanks for your help,
Dan

Comment: Have you signed up for webmaster tools?

Comment: Yes, I did and submitted the foreign homepages to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the advice from Google regarding multilingual sites; [Multi-regional and multilingual sites](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192)